# Unable to create custom marker icon in Mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox

I have to display custom icon for the marker in the mapbox.

I am trying with this code :

```
IconFactory mIconFactory = IconFactory.getInstance(this);
        Drawable mIconDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_directions_boat_black_18dp);
        Icon icon = mIconFactory.fromDrawable(mIconDrawable);
```

> **Problem:** with IconFactory i.e shows there is no class for IconFactory.

And for the marker

```
mapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)
                         .icon())
```

When I was trying with this above marker code Getting

> **Problem :** there is no code for icon().

I am using

```
 compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:2.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
```

in the build.gradle.

I thought my problem is with this map box library. Can you please help me. Thanks in Advance.

You can see my code here.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please add this in your gradle dependency.

```
dependencies {
       compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
}
```

Comment: This is related to google maps. But My project uses mapbox libraries only.

Comment: You will surely gonna use this.

Comment: Can you explain what this library will do? Why I am asking this means My project is restricted to not to use google libraries.

Comment: If you use this dependency then only you will be able to use IconFactory class.

Comment: I have changed library version.

compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:3.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
It's worked for me. As you suggested I will also add this library in build.gradle. Anyway Thanks very much dear. You saved my time.

Comment: Nice talking man. If you like my suggestion then kindly vote up :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99306/discussion-between-tricky-solutions-and-shoeb-siddique).

Answer (score 0):

just update your library dependency as below :

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.3.0'
```

and then you can use it just like you did earlier :

```
    IconFactory mIconFactory = IconFactory.getInstance(this);
    Drawable mIconDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_directions_boat_black_18dp);
    Icon icon = mIconFactory.fromDrawable(mIconDrawable);
```